# Wire cut detection GPIO

Tags: transistors

I am looking at establish a circuit allowing to detect when one or two wire are cut such as a tamper system. When the wire are cut it should signal this a GPIO.
I suppose I need to use a transistor connected to GPIO but I have a bit some difficulty to see how.

Comment: *I suppose I need to use a transistor connected to GPIO* Why would you need a transistor ? If you connect the far end of the wire to ground, configure the GPIO as a pull-up then you can detect when it's cut (as the GPIO would become high). No transistor needed.

Comment: I am concerned about the impedance of the wire. I can not control the length so I am not sure how the GPIO would react to it.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the impedance of the wire ? You're not using it for high speed data communication so characteristic impedance does not matter. Are you concerned with the series resistance ? Even a 10 km wire will have much less resistance then the pull up resistor in a GPIO. You worry too much !

Comment: @fakemoustache, thank you for your answer. It clarify everything :)

Comment: You can do this with a micro controller and a bit of C: if pin1 = LOW; I.E the wire was cut, when its low you can then put another pin HIGH to trigger an alarm

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA8UqT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. GPIO normally pulled low by tamper loop. Cutting loop causes GPIO to be pulled high by R1.*

C1 will help eliminate any noise on a long tamper loop.

Comment: How did you choose the 1k ohm value ? I plan to use CC1310 GPIO for this.

Comment: The 1 k ohm is determined by experience, experienced circuit designers can just suck these values out of our thumbs :-) 10 kohm will also work fine and so will 100 kohm. You can also use the internal pull-up if the GPIO has that feature. The 100 nF capacitor is a good suggestion. But if you have a problem with it, just try without the capacitor and see if that is OK.

Comment: I chose the 1k to drive a reasonable current around the loop as I saw from your comments that you were concerned about the length of the loop. Generally low impedance (resistance) circuits are less susceptible to noise than high impedance but going too low just wastes current. 1 kΩ on a 5 V supply will use 5 mA. (I = V/R.) If you're running on battery this may be too much and you could go to 10 k, etc.

Comment: the loop will be no more tha 30CM but I am unsure yet which width will be used.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to detecting change in voltage on the GPIO pin would be to use a dedicated [current loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop) controller. There exists many [4–20mA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/4-20ma/info) control circuits that will have a indicator pin for when there is no current flowing which you can monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Pull up the GPIO externally to HIGH. Configure a cheap uC to trigger an interrupt when the pin value changes from HIGH->LOW.When you enter the ISR,you'l know that your circuit was tampered/cut.

If you want to go a little further,you could use an [Event Monitor](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF2127.pdf) to capture such an event for you and log the time when it occurred.

Note: The value of the wire must remain at a known value and not change/toggle. That is always HIGH. Or if you need to detect a LOW->HIGH,you can configure appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what level of tampering you want to be able to detect.  The minimum approach is described by transistor.

Note that a clever tamperer can simply ground the top line, then cut the loop and perform mischief.  A more robust system uses two pins.  The processor drives one with different values, then checks the other to verify the new output value is detected.  For extra credit, you make the values pseudo-random, like what comes from something like a CRC calculation.

However, all this only describes the logic, not the real implementation.  I would not just want to connect processor pins directly to external wires, especially when tampering is a possibility.  At least any processor input should be protected.  CMOS inputs are high impedance, and there is no reason to require high speed, so 100 kΩ or so between any external connection and a processor input is a good idea.

Depending on the level of abuse you want to be able to live thru, you may want your own clamping or rely on the built-in clamping circuitry of the processor.  The processor may not be specified to operate correctly with current thru its clamping circuitry, but it should survive.

For good tamper resistance, I'd say that external lines should be able to tolerate being connected to whatever line power is where the device will be used.  That means 120 VAC here in North America, for example.

Comment: i was condering indeed the issue of the smart tamperer who put to ground the device to spoof the system. I was indeed thinking to the idea you are proposing but i have no idea how to implement it. The device is a wearable device, so it is powered on battery, not on 120V AC...

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, it would be useful to explain what you think is wrong, misleading, or badly written.